# Why does MySQL have high CPU usage when I copy ten databases into one?

Tags: mysql, cpu-usage

I have a MySQL version 5.5.49 server using MyISAM tables. I have 10 databases with approximately 170,000 tables in all of them combined. The Windows 2012 R2 server has 46.9GB of RAM and 48 cores. With this setup, MySQL uses approximately 5%-10% of the CPU with around 300 users hammering away on the application. I need to create a single database for an application upgrade with all these tables. When I create a single database, and copy all the tables into the one database folder, MySQL starts pegging all the cores with just over 175 users and the application goes to a crawl. Any suggestions?

The MySQL user the application uses was created a long time ago with these rights:

```
grant all privileges on *.* to 'appUser'@'%' identified by 'somepassword' with grant option
```

When I run 'show full processlist' I get a ton of lines like the following (With different Hosts and Times). I don't get these results with 10 databases with the same code, plus these are all MySQL internal queries. I do not see any of my actual queries:

```
Id  User    Host    db  Command Time    State   Info
101 appUser 10.1.1.20:58414 dbnew   Query   45  checking  permissions   
SELECT TABLE_NAME, TABLE_COMMENT, TABLE_TYPE FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = DATABASE()AND ( TABLE_TYPE='BASE TABLE' OR TABLE_TYPE='VIEW' ) AND TABLE_NAME LIKE 'randomTableName'
108 appUser 10.1.1.21:49393 dbnew   Query   41  checking permissions    
SELECT TABLE_NAME, TABLE_COMMENT, TABLE_TYPE FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = DATABASE()AND ( TABLE_TYPE='BASE TABLE' OR TABLE_TYPE='VIEW' ) AND TABLE_NAME LIKE 'randomTableName'

.
.
.
511 appUser 127.0.0.1:53015 NULL    Query   0   NULL    show full processlist
```

And finally, here is the my.ini:

```
[mysqld]

default-storage-engine=MYISAM
skip-name-resolve
wait_timeout=259200

port=3306

sql-mode="STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION"

# CACHES AND LIMITS #
max-connections                = 2000
max-allowed-packet             = 3M

tmp-table-size                 = 64M
max-heap-table-size            = 64M

#query-cache-type              = 0
query-cache-size               = 0M

thread-cache-size              = 100

open-files-limit               = 65536

table-definition-cache         = 2M
table-open-cache               = 256K
table_cache                    = 10000

#*** MyISAM Specific options

myisam_max_sort_file_size       =100G
myisam_sort_buffer_size         =39M

key_buffer_size                 =6G

read_buffer_size                =64K
read_rnd_buffer_size            =256K
sort_buffer_size                =256K
```

At this point in time in is not feasible to go to InnoDB.

Comment: Why do you have so many tables?

Comment: @Dai That is the way it is. I do not have control over it.

Comment: 'Users hammering away at the database' is limited by how fast they can type. Copying databases is limited bby how fast they can be read from the disk. You should expect several orders of magnitude more CPU usage,

Comment: This does no feel like it's a MyISAM/innoDB table engine issue.. This feel like this is a disk partition table problem (340000 data and index) files in one directory a pretty big amount.. you can set the `DATA DIRECTORY, INDEX DIRECTORY` options in a `CREATE TABLE` statements to separate the (tables) between directories.

Comment: @RaymondNijland Wouldn't that be a indicate a slow disk read/write and not MySQL using the CPU?

Comment: "Wouldn't that be a indicate a slow disk read/write and not MySQL using the CPU? " Hard to tell.. We don't know what kind of queries are running.. Besides `INSERT INTO table (...) SELECT ...` kind of queries are known at eat (lots) CPU resources/time don't know if you run those?

Comment: How are you copying over? You should be able to `RENAME TABLE origdb.tblname TO destdb.tablename` without significant IO.

Comment: Agreed with Raymond - too many files for NTFS. There are better choices on other operating systems for maintaining huge directories but there are very few cases where having so many tables is the right solution.

Comment: @RaymondNijland NTFS was designed for hundreds of thousands of files per directory, and if that was the problem it would be disk-bound, not CPU-bound.

Comment: "NTFS was designed for hundreds of thousands of files per directory, and if that was the problem it would be disk-bound, not CPU-bound." isn't it wierd that the server should handle it when the files (tables) where separated under 10 directories (databases) but not merged when all the files (tables) together into one directory (database)..? @user207421 I was talking about disk partition table in general not about NTFS (you assuming that what the topicstarter is using)  Besides we don't know the queries which are running and some queries in MySQL can in fact be CPU-bounded.instead of disk-bound

Comment: @RaymondNijland The problem is stated to be in the copying step, not in how it runs afterwards.

Comment: "The problem is stated to be in the copying step," like i comment before to the topicstarter @user207421. "Besides `INSERT INTO table (...) SELECT ...` kind of queries are known at eat (lots) CPU resources/time don't know if you run those?"

Comment: @user207421 The problem is how it runs afterwards. I am not ruling out too many files, but could it be how the tables are combined into one? If they are copied and pasted into one folder, does that mess with all the MySQL schema tables?

Comment: @RaymondNijland There are not any queries of that type. I would approximate the queries are 90% selects and 10% inserts and updates.

Comment: Well @DarinBallweg non optimized `SELECT` (with `ORDER BY`/`GROUP BY` clauses) queries can make a (disk) temporary table,  the copy from RAM memory to disk will also also eat CPU  time/cycles forget to mention that it in mine other comments it becomes even worse when MySQL needs to use a sort algoritme on a temporary table.... those settings `tmp-table-size                 = 64M
max-heap-table-size            = 64M` are not that great for allowing RAM based temporary tables in MySQL

Comment: Thanks for the info @RaymondNijland. I also failed to mention in my post as to why do I see all TABLE_SCHEMA queries, that MySQL does, in the show processlist and none of my actual queries. Wouldn't my queries show up there if they were the culprit slowing stuff down? I am not sure.

Comment: "I also failed to mention in my post as to why do I see all TABLE_SCHEMA queries, that MySQL does." I think most likely a MySQL IDE is causing that when users are opening databases....i also believe when you query `information_schema` database views MySQL makes disk searches and needs to open the table structure file always to get the meta data.